# Apahce Website - Uploading files and download

Tags: apache2, downloads, cloud, ip

I just recently made an Apache Webserver for uploading my files. The website ip is 173.65.17.127. I'd like to upload files and be able to download them remotely, I got MySQL, Apache, and PHP aswell as PHPMyAdmin. 
 I looked on the internet and I can't find a way to make my site a cloud for uploads and downloads... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to Setup a OwnClound5 Server on Ubuntu 12.04,12.10

Here we can see how to make a Cloud Storage Server same as like google Drive or Dropbox
we can get the files from these clouds everywere and from every devices

Here i'm Using IP 192.168.1.200

Here is the Official Website Link

```
http://owncloud.org/
```

Step 1

Then update the Repo Using

```
 sudo apt-get update 

sysadmin@linuxmental:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for sysadmin: 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
```

Step 2

Then Upgrade the OS using

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

For Installing the Owncloud first we need to install and configure LAMP server

For Installing LAMP Server Visit here

[LAMP Server Setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

Step 3

Install the Prerequest for Owncloud setup

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php-xml-parser php5-intl smbclient curl libcurl3 php5-curl
```

Output is here :

sysadmin@linuxmental:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-gd php-xml-parser php5-intl smbclient curl libcurl3 php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5-gd is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autotools-dev libicu48 libltdl-dev libltdl7 libssl-dev
  libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 libtalloc2 libtdb1 libtool libwbclient0 m4 php-pear
  php5-dev samba-common samba-common-bin shtool zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:

This will install some of the dependices need for the Owncloud setup

Step 4

And we need to enable the module for apache Enable it using

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite   --> Enables the rewrite module 

 sudo a2enmod headers    --> Enables the header module
```

Output :

sysadmin@linuxmental:/var/www/owncloud/data# sudo a2enmod rewrite
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart

sysadmin@linuxmental:/var/# sudo a2enmod headers
Enabling module headers.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart

Step 5

We need to change the apache2 config file for rewrite 
Use the command to change it

sysadmin@linuxmental:~$ `sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

Change the configuration from

```
Allowoverride None
```

to

```
Allowoverride All
```

Virtual host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Save the Virtual host file and Exit using wq!

Step 6

Restart the apache Service using

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

sysadmin@linuxmental:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                 ... waiting                                                             [ OK ]

Step 7

Create a DATABASE For owncloud a Bind it with a password

Login to the mysql using -u User root (the user) -p using a password 
Here i'm using the password admin123$
use your password which you have setted while installing the LAMP Server mysql_secure_installation

sysadmin@linuxmental:~$ `mysql -u root -p`
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 36
Server version: 5.5.22-0ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

Create a Database

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE owncloud;
```

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Grant the Created database to localhost with password admin123$

mysql> `GRANT ALL ON owncloud.* TO 'owncloud'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin123$';`
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Flush the Privilages for Database to get clear

mysql> `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

If you need to See the Created Database use the command

```
mysql> `SHOW DATABASES;`
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| owncloud           |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Quit from the mysql

mysql> `\q`
Bye

Step 8

Download and install the Owncloud 5 from the official Site

Download using wget command

```
wget http://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-latest.tar.bz2
```

sysadmin@linuxmental:~$ wget http://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-latest.tar.bz2
--2013-11-02 10:46:52--  http://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-latest.tar.bz2
Resolving download.owncloud.org (download.owncloud.org)... 50.30.33.234
Connecting to download.owncloud.org (download.owncloud.org)|50.30.33.234|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 15147476 (14M) [application/x-bzip]
Saving to: `owncloud-latest.tar.bz2'

100%[=====================================================================>] 15,147,476  26.6K/s   in 9m 41s

2013-11-02 10:56:43 (25.5 KB/s) - `owncloud-latest.tar.bz2' saved [15147476/15147476]

Step 9

Extract the Downloaded package using tar command

Extrat it First using jvf

sysadmin@linuxmental:~$ `tar -xjvf owncloud-latest.tar.bz2`

Step 10

Move the extracted files to /var/www/

sysadmin@linuxmental:~$ `sudo mv owncloud /var/www/`

Step 11

Change the ownership of `/var/www/owncloud to www-data`

sysadmin@linuxmental:/var$

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data owncloud/
```

Step 12

Then navigate to the Web Browser and fireup your IP 192.168.1.200/owncloud

Follow the Setup Instruction as Follows and get install it ...

Happy Uploading your Files and share ...

Comment: Welcome Most ...